# Avoid execution overlap

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
Private Sub NewRecallLabel_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myrecalllabel As Label = TryCast(sender, Label)

    Dim SpeechSynthesizer As New SpeechSynthesizer

    SpeechSynthesizer.Speak("Ticket number " & TTSTicket & ", please proceed to counter " & TTSCounter)

End Sub
```

What happens is, when the TextChanged event fires, the UI freezes while performing the speak code.
I know using SpeakAsync will solve the problem but when multiple TextChanged event is fired, the audio overlaps - I don't want that to happen.

Can anyone show me how could I avoid this?

Comment: possibly same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419961/c-sharp-threadpool-queueuserworkitem-use)

Comment: Which .NET version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting .NET v4 sir.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I've deleted my answer as it's intended for 4.5 and above. While a fully async version is entirely possible with 4.0, it is a lot more cumbersome. Please use @Gubr's blocking solution for the time being.

Comment: I have tried @Gubr's solution but it freezes the UI.

Comment: On the other hand, if I use `SpeakAsync` the sound overlaps.

Comment: of course and of course. The workaround for Gubr's solution would be to offload the entire method to the thread pool, but it's a bit of an ugly hack. Are you stuck with .NET 4.0 for this project with no chance of upgrading?

Comment: Right not I'm sticking to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

We've established that you're using .NET 4.0, so `SemaphoreSlim` goes out the window.

First I'd try getting around the problem by sharing an instance of `SpeechSynthesizer` and using `SpeakAsyncCancelAll` when a new request comes in:

```
Private SpeechSynthesizer As New SpeechSynthesizer

Private Sub NewRecallLabel_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myrecalllabel As Label = TryCast(sender, Label)

    SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll()
    SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Ticket number " & TTSTicket & ", please proceed to counter " & TTSCounter)
End Sub
```

**Oringinal answer**

Since you can't use `SyncLock` in an async context and you want non-blocking execution, your best bet is to use a `SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)` to get async mutex semantics (similar to what @Gubr suggested, except async):

```
Private Semaphore As New SemaphoreSlim(1, 1)

Private Sub NewRecallLabel_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myrecalllabel As Label = TryCast(sender, Label)
    Dim SpeechSynthesizer As New SpeechSynthesizer

    Await Semaphore.WaitAsync()

    Try
      ' We're inside the protected region now.
      Await SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Ticket number " & TTSTicket & ", please proceed to counter " & TTSCounter)
    Finally
      Semaphore.Release()
    End Try

End Sub
```

I'd also consider wiring in some form of throttling and/or auto-cancellation, because the code as it stands will *not* work very well if the label text changes rapidly (i.e. each subsequent speech request will have to wait for previous ones to complete).

Comment: I thought it will work since lock statement is wrapped in a normal synchronous method whichis being called asynchronously. But maybe I was wrong as I said I have not tried it really. your solution seems neat

Comment: I'm getting an error: 'WaitAsync' is not a member of 'System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim'

Comment: this is so deep! Sorry I'm a newbie.

Comment: @Gubr, `SyncLock` will work fine in any synchronous code regions, but you can't have an `Await` statement inside of it. Since the ultimate goal (as per the question) is non-blocking execution I chose to recommend a synchronization primitive which supports async scenarios out of the box.

Comment: @carlot0820, sounds like you're running .NET 4.0 or below. I've also just noticed that `SpeakAsync` is also a `void` (I erroneously assumed that it returned `Task`), which invalidates my above answer. I will rework it when I have a minute; for the time being please go with Gubr's suggestion.

Comment: Thank you @KirillShlenskiy for your response but the succeeding `Speak` codes must wait for the first one to finish before executing the new one - not cancel (which I think the `SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsyncCancelAll()` does). My bad, I think I have not mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe using lock with asynchronous call will help it would look like this:

```
Private Sub NewRecallLabel_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myrecalllabel As Label = TryCast(sender, Label)
    Dim SpeechSynthesizer As New SpeechSynthesizer
        SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Ticket number " & TTSTicket & ", please proceed to counter " & TTSCounter)
End Sub
```

Inside your Async call use [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t.aspx):

```
Private messagesLock As New Object
SyncLock messagesLock
    SpeechSynthesizer.Speak("the sync one")
End SyncLock
```

I didn't try this but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I want using a `BackgroudWorker`. I placed the `SpeakAsync` code to the `BackgroudWorker` and replaced the

`SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakAsync("Ticket number " & TTSTicket & ", please proceed to counter " & TTSCounter)`

with

```
      If SpeechBackgroundWorker.IsBusy = False Then

         TTSCounter = CRichTextBox.Text
         TTSTicket = TRichTextBox.Text

         SpeechBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()

         Exit Sub

      End If
```

It successfully queues the speeches and it doesn't affect the UI thread. Hope this helps!